# MySql query to retrieve a conversation between 2 users

Tags: mysql

I'm having a quick issue I could use an opinion on. I'm attempting to write a MySQL query that pulls all the messages from a conversation that is exclusively between two users. 
I need to be able to pull messages **sent by 'user1'** that are **sent to 'user2'**, and messages **sent by 'user2'** that are **sent to 'user1'**.

I've dabbled a bit and I've currently got the 4 conditions needed for my query to execute (see below). I've been trying to work out what way to structure it to get the specific data I need though.

```
    SELECT privatemessage_message, privatemessage_time_created, privatemessage_sent_by, privatemessage_sent_to 
    FROM tbl_privatemessages 
    WHERE privatemessage_sent_by = 1 
       OR privatemessage_sent_by = 2 
       OR privatemessage_sent_to = 1
       OR privatemessage_sent_to = 2
    ORDER BY privatemessage_time_created ASC
```

*For context :* 
This is going to be used within a PHP MySQL website with AJAX being used for the private messaging. I'm fine withthem sides of it, but this particular SQL query is a nuisance.

Any help is **greatly** appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AND` to combine the sender and recipient, and `OR` to combine the different directions.

```
SELECT privatemessage_message, privatemessage_time_created, privatemessage_sent_by, privatemessage_sent_to 
FROM tbl_privatemessages 
WHERE (privatemessage_sent_by = 1 AND privatemessage_sent_to = 2)
   OR (privatemessage_sent_to = 1 AND privatemessage_sent_by = 2)
ORDER BY privatemessage_time_created ASC
```

Comment: @MichaelO. Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Works as intended. Thank you for your time @Barmar